# Return a Regex Match excluding parts of the match

Tags: regex, grep

Given I have a Twiki page with the following source:

```
| *Region* | *Owner* | *Partner / Project* | *Type* | *Description* | *Timeline* | *Flag* | *Update* |

| Region 1 | Olaf | RedHat | type1 | nothing to do at topic 1 | time1 | Progress | TBC |

| Region 2 | Olaf | Gentoo | type2 | nothing to do at topic 2 | time2 | | none |
```

I want to construct a regex pattern that should match everything after

> Update* |

It's a simple problem, folks!

Comment: But there are nothing after `Update*|`. Can you post your desired output?

Comment: | Region 1 | Olaf | RedHat | type1 | nothing to do at topic 1 | time1 | Progress | TBC |

| Region 2 | Olaf | Gentoo | type2 | nothing to do at topic 2 | time2 | | none |

Comment: Why not to delete the first line? The rest is what you want, I guess.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean... delete?! Deletion of the source is of course not an option!!! I have to match stuff not alter stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by egrep you mean egrep binary in *nix then you can do:

```
egrep -o "\*Update\*.*" <<< $(<file)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
*Update* | | Region 1 | Olaf | RedHat | type1 | nothing to do at topic 1 | time1 | Progress | TBC | | Region 2 | Olaf | Gentoo | type2 | nothing to do at topic 2 | time2 | | none |
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want??

```
awk 'o;/\*Update\* \|$/{o=1}' yourFile
```

**output**

```
| Region 1 | Olaf | RedHat | type1 | nothing to do at topic 1 | time1 | Progress | TBC |

| Region 2 | Olaf | Gentoo | type2 | nothing to do at topic 2 | time2 | | none |
```